# Imposing an intercept on an LMM

Tags: r, multiple-regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am looking at the effect of threats on populations of animals using mixed effects modelling. However, when interpreting the LMM's output the intercept is based on one of the threats, which is in overall decline. Is there a way to impose an intercept in an LMM that I can set the values for?

When I make a results table, for anyone who doesn't read the entire report I want them to still undertand that even a single threat will cause population decline and not have the reader mistakenly think some threats don't have negative impacts.

The model I am using is below with the top of it's output:

```
x4 <- lmer(avg_lamda ~ (Threat1_Cat*Threat2_Cat) + (1|Species) + (1|Family)
     + (1|Country), data=rm.null.all)

summary(x4)
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Species  (Intercept) 0.020094 0.14175 
 Family   (Intercept) 0.003433 0.05859 
 Country  (Intercept) 0.002904 0.05389 
 Residual             0.007279 0.08532 
Number of obs: 367, groups:  Species, 220; Family, 75; Country, 50

Fixed effects:
                             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                 -0.008193   0.199809  -0.041
Threat1_Cat1                -0.109004   0.101959  -1.069
Threat1_Cat11               -0.102301   0.221089  -0.463
Threat1_Cat12               -0.042615   0.207029  -0.206
Threat1_Cat2                -0.133920   0.262490  -0.510
Threat1_Cat3                 0.054627   0.100086   0.546
Threat1_Cat4                -0.030259   0.190125  -0.159
```

Comment: You could not fit an intercept, so your groups would all be in the table, using `0 + (Threat1_Cat*Threat2_Cat) + (1|Species) + (1|Family) + (1|Country)`, but you should check whether that affects inference. (It seems fine as long as there is no continuous predictors.)

Comment: Or you might fit the model as you do now, but show the predicted group means, perhaps by plotting them with their confidence intervals. This is hard to say without example data and a good understanding of it. This Q might be better suited for Cross Validated.